# Docker build ubuntu:xenial issue

Tags: python, ubuntu, jenkins, docker, dockerfile

I try to build a docker image with docker-py in Jenkins.

## The scripts looks like this:

```
# Let's build the toolchain-base-image
from io import BytesIO
from docker import Client
from pprint import pprint
import sys

cli = Client(base_url="tcp://127.0.0.1:4243")
#cli = Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
GCC_VERSION_TAG="4_9"
with open("/path/to/docker-" + GCC_VERSION_TAG + "-gcc-base-image-dockerfile", mode="r") as dockerfile:
  f = BytesIO(dockerfile.read().encode('utf-8'))
  try:
      response = [pprint(line["stream"]) for line in cli.build(fileobj=f, nocache=False, rm=True, tag='gcc49/toolchain-base_'+GCC_VERSION_TAG, decode=True, pull=True)]
  except:
      raise IOError("Invalid Dockerfile!")
  if response != "None":
      pprint(response[0])

print "Create container"
container = cli.create_container(image='gcc49/toolchain-base_' + GCC_VERSION_TAG + ':latest',stdin_open=True, tty=True, volumes=['/ssd', '/opt', '/nfs/'], host_config=cli.create_host_config(binds=['/ssd:/ssd:rw','/opt/:/opt:ro','/nfs:/nfs:rw']))
print "Start container"
cli.start(container=container.get('Id'))
log_stream_list = []
[log_stream_list.append(l) for l in cli.logs(container, stream=True)]

print "".join(log_stream_list)
```

## My dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
MAINTAINER Gino
ENV CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE /path/to/toolchainfile.toolchain
ENV SOURCE_DIR /path/to/src_root
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install -y python-cheetah build-essential gcc-4.9 cmake
RUN groupadd group
RUN useradd -G group -m -s /bin/bash user 
RUN echo "user:user" | chpasswd
ENV HOME /home/user
ENV SHELL /bin/bash
ENV JAVA_HOME /opt/jdk1.8.0_65/
RUN mkdir -p /home/user/docker-build
WORKDIR /home/user/docker-build
# Set permissions
RUN chown -R user:group /home/*
USER user
# Start build on run
ENTRYPOINT cmake -DBUILD_JAVA=0 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DeveloperRelease -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE} -DPROJECT_CONFIGURATION="project@${SOURCE_DIR}/dir" ${SOURCE_DIR} && make -j4
```

## My issue:

```
15:37:27 [docker-test_job] $ python /tmp/hudson5834793409651253293.py
15:37:29 u'Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:16.04\n'
15:37:29 Traceback (most recent call last):
15:37:29   File "/tmp/hudson5834793409651253293.py", line 15, in <module>
15:37:29     raise IOError("Invalid Dockerfile!")
15:37:29 IOError: Invalid Dockerfile!
15:37:29 Build step 'Execute Python script' marked build as failure
15:37:29 Stopping all containers
15:37:29 Finished: FAILURE
```

When I try it with ubuntu:14.04 it works pretty fine. Got anyone an idea?
Thanks for helping!

Update: Some additional information: Docker 1.5 + Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. 
When I run on console

```
docker build -t name/tag -f dockerfilename .
```

it works too and the docker builds the image as expected.

Comment: Did you try with :
    FROM ubuntu:latest

Also, why not :
    FROM java:latest

Comment: If it works in the commandline, then I suspect that there's something in your script. **However** Docker 1.5 is no longer supported by Docker Hub, are you sure you're able to actually *pull* `ubuntu:16.04` from Docker Hub?

Comment: @Sabmit `ubuntu:latest` points to the latest LTS release; given that 16.04 is not yet released, `:latest` currently is an alias for `14.04`, not `16.04`

Comment: 14.04 is related to latest.

ubuntu                  14.04               97434d46f197        10 days ago         188 MB
ubuntu                  latest              97434d46f197        10 days ago         188 MB

Comment: @thaJeztah yes, I was doubting too:
ubuntu                  16.04               537089ecf650        10 days ago         119 MB
but it worked. I am also sure it is in script but I can't figure out why it works for 14.04 but not for 16.04.

Comment: First check if `docker pull ubuntu:16.04` actually works. Also check if you didn't by accident add a "BOM" header when editing the Dockerfile; I ran into that once. Perhaps try if you strip everything from the Dockerfile, and only keep the first line, then keep adding lines until you get the error

Comment: First worked as you can see below:). Do you mean with BOM - Byte order mark? 

`docker pull ubuntu:16.04`

`16.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
6d3a6d998241: Already exists 
606b08bdd0f3: Already exists 
1d99b95ffc1c: Already exists 
a3ed95caeb02: Already exists 
Digest: sha256:d31053573e3311e3ef9e03f26d8d13bdd1c0f9bbd24f93a3ed4f0e4c4f9faaa7
Status: Image is up to date for ubuntu:16.04`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now. I figured out that I can't use `pull=True`. I think a return code > 0 comes  back and Jenkins interpret it as an error. Thanks for any help. :) Below is the code which work.

```
[pprint(line["stream"]) for line in cli.build(fileobj=f, nocache=False, rm=True, tag='gcc49/toolchain-base_'+GCC_VERSION_TAG, decode=True)]
```

## Update

I was wrong. In upper line I try to match the key "stream". But if docker pulls the image. There is no such key.

```
10:28:06  u'progress': u'[===================================>               ] 36.18 MB/50.84 MB',
10:28:06  u'progressDetail': {u'current': 36175872, u'total': 50841331},
10:28:06  u'status': u'Extracting'}
```

Now everything is clear. :)

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing you need to give the path to the Docker file (including the name of your Dockerfile) while in your python script it seems like you are only providing the directory where Dockerfile is present. try changing the part

open("/path/to/docker-" + GCC_VERSION_TAG + "-gcc-base-image", mode="r")'

to

open("/path/to/docker-" + GCC_VERSION_TAG + "-gcc-base-image/dockerfilename", mode="r")

and see if it works

Comment: Hi, sorry docker-" + GCC_VERSION_TAG + "-gcc-base-image is already the file name, I got this already working with another dockerfile where I only changed the ubuntu version. I updated my post to make it more clear it's a dockerfile.:)